Should parameter names describe their object type?
I'm unsure whether parameter names should describe their object types or if shorter, more concise names are preferable.
Consider the following two method implementations:
public void PrintPoint(MyVeryCustomPoint point)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"X: {point.X}, Y: {point.Y}, Z: {point.Z}");
}

Versus:
public void PrintPoint(MyVeryCustomPoint myVeryCustomPoint)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"X: {myVeryCustomPoint.X}, Y: {myVeryCustomPoint.Y}, Z: {myVeryCustomPoint.Z}");
}

Since this is a very simple demonstation using the first version looks better. But in more complex scenarios, or with a lot of overload methods, or by using different similar variables inside the method body the second approach would be the better one.
In the end I wonder if it is good practice to do all parameter names like the second one for sake of consistency?
My question here is more about general conventions, standards, rather than the specific use case.
I work on a complex application where some methods/endpoints use the first approach, while others use second one without very clear cause, so I wondered if it would be worth to standardize this.

https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/

see also Hungarian notation


I'm unsure whether parameter names should describe their object types or if shorter, more concise names are preferable.

Neither. They should be named so you know what the variable is used for, its role. Both point and myVeryCustomPoint are bad names and both only look acceptable, because your example is so small it's pointless (excuse the pun).
Types have no use in naming variables. It's redundant information. You already know the type. You could as well name it x if you have no use for the name itself:
public void Print(MyVeryCustomPoint x)

In any example just a little bit more complex, it should be obvious that naming by type and you should name by usage:
public void Move(
    MyVeryCustomPoint source, 
    MyVeryCustomPoint destination)

Or
public void Move(
    MyVeryCustomPoint from, 
    MyVeryCustomPoint to)

Or
public void Move(
    MyVeryCustomPoint start,
    MyVeryCustomPoint end)

And if it gets more complicated, you may need information that is connected to your type:
public void Move(
    MyVeryCustomPoint startPoint,
    MyVeryCustomPoint endPoint,
    double startSpeed,
    double endSpeed)

But you could just as well name it
public void Move(
    MyVeryCustomPoint startCoordinate, 
    MyVeryCustomPoint endCoordinate,
    double startSpeed, 
    double endSpeed)

In the real world, give your variables names that communicate what they are used for.

Similarly, the method shouldn't be named PrintPoint, but just Print as it prints, and the parameter is a point, so that is known.

In this specific case x would be a terrible name for the variable, since you'd be referring to the child properties as x.x and x.y. But yes, agree in general.

"You already know the type. " this is one of the reasons I dislike overuse of auto in C++ programs (unless it is a lambda or an iterator with complex typenames etc. that aren't very informative).

"You already know the type" for statically typed languages (as C# in OP's question). For contrast, in SmallTalk it's very common for parameter names to mention the (general) class the arguments are (sort of) espected to have. I think.

Note that giving variables names that communicate what they are used for does not exclude the possibility of naming them after their type.  For example, UTF8StringToUTF32BE() is likely to take a parameter named utf8string.

@Mark That someone did something doesn't make it good, even if it made it into a very popular framework. An (extension) method for utf8string called ToUTF32BE might have been better.

@PabloH: As I recall, even with that, if it is like Apps Hungarian or Systems Hungarian notation, it is common to abbreviate the type (i.e mvcpPoint rather than myverycustompointPoint.). Though there are reasons why not to do that, which is its own question, explaining why the stronger take is made here.

@Mark: If a function takes separate source and desitnation arguments, I'd view src and dest as better names.  If a function accepts a single argument and the function name describes what the function does to that argument, I'd generally use a name which is loosely associated with the type of the argument, e.g. p for pointer, x for a numeric parameter, st for string, etc.  The idea is not so much to encode the type, but rather avoid any confusion that might come from e.g. having a structure representing point named x, when x is also the name of a field within that structure.

I disagree about point being a bad name in the given example, as this method is clearly designed to handle any MyVeryCustomPoint regardless of its context. I do agree that if the method has a specific context, that the param should be named accordingly (your examples are good instances of such names). But Print(MyVeryCustomPoint point) seems fine for a method whose job it is to print any point regardless of what kind of point this object represents, contextually speaking. The method omits such context by design as it's not relevant to the task at hand.

The answer is always "do what makes the code clearer". Is it vitally important for a developer working on PrintPoint to always remember that the parameter is of type MyVeryCustomPoint rather than just a generic Point type? If so, consider making it explicit. If it's not, go with the short name.
Your example is honestly a few orders of magnitude too simple to be able to say any more than that, as your MyVeryCustomPoint type doesn't seem to have any behaviour beyond a 3 parameter POJO.

In general, names in source code should aim to be reasonably short whilst being distinctive within the scope of the job which that developer (or those developers/that development team) performs, and within any separate contexts which the developer recognises within that job. Different jobs can be somewhat particular in this regard.
Where relevant (i.e. where the terminology is externally visible), terminology should also integrate with that shown to the users in the screens, and with terms which users employ generally for discussion.
So if you were defining a method in the MyVeryCustomPoint class, it might be sufficient to name the method just Print.
But you'd have to decide for yourself whether Print is sufficiently clear in the context of your own job, including the subtleties of the wider codebase, any naming systems you have.
Terminology design is a hard task requiring considerable language skills and involvement with the application area, and unfortunately software development tends to require a lot of additional terminology to be developed.

I see, my question was more about the parameter name and industry standards/conventions
rather than the method name. In our codebase some methods use first aproach some use second without clear reasons

@Abcd, ah I see your point. There could be special reasons for calling parameters after their types on a case basis (including perhaps distinguishing different parameters at the call site, rather than inside the method itself), but there is no general reason to do so. point meets a general good standard for a parameter name. In your codebase, the variation in approaches may be for specific reasons (which you'd have to ask your developer about, or be more familiar with the codebase to perceive), or it may just be arbitrary/stylistic decisions of that developer.

Code style is much a matter of personal preference.  However, in this case, there is some prior art.  Hungarian Notation did encode type information in a variable name.  It fell out of favor some time ago, although there are a few people who still find value in it.

Hungarian Notation is for capturing semantic constraints that the type system of the language is too weak to express. For example, distinguishing between a tainted and sanitized string in C. But that is not the case in the OP's example: the type system of C# is perfectly capable of capturing the semantic constraint that an object must be a member of a type. One of the reasons why Hungarian Notation seems to become less relevant is that type system are becoming better at capturing semantic constraints, and languages are being extended with features like annotations and attributes.
